# How to check the array key matches specific string in php

Tags: php, regex

```
 $array = array(
                "[ci_id]" => '144309',
                "[NEW flag]" => 'No', 
                "[[*PRODUCT_IMAGE_ANCHOR1*]]" => ,
                "[[*PRODUCT_IMAGE2*]]" => '154154154' 
          );
```

I need to get the elements which have pattern like `'[['`.
I have tried by using `array_key_exists()`:-

`if (array_key_exists('[*PRODUCT_IMAGE2*]', $array))`

But i want to match only with `'['`

Can any one help me on this

Comment: Do you have a bit of code which is valid PHP?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually try to express with that invalid array notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `preg_grep()` with `array_keys()` like below:-

```
$matches  = preg_grep ('/[.*?]/i', array_keys($array));

print_r($matches);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/817299

Or can do it using `strpos()` also:-

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
  if(strpos($key,'[')!== false){
    echo $key ."is matched with [*] pattern";
    echo PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/817297

Comment: Thanks you, i use foreach. i got what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give the true for the key with double [[ in if you know the element index value

```
$test = array("a"=>'a',"[a]"=>'a',"[[a]]"=>'a',"b"=>'b',"c"=>'c');
var_dump(array_key_exists("[[a]]", $test));
```

If you can checking the keys to determine if [[ even exist then the following code should work

```
$test = array("a"=>'a',"[a]"=>'a','[[a]]'=>'a',"b"=>'b',"c"=>'c');
$values = array();
foreach ($test as $key=>$value) {
    if (stripos('[[', substr($key, 0, 2)) !== false) {
        array_push($values, $value);
    }
}
```